# Restore specific date from mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

i have a big mysql dump-file since 2015 i want to restore all data form 2020 and 2021

Note : schema have a lot of tables and every table have it's own data

and we didn't want all table we need only 3 table with specific date

for example i have table called "datamart_queue_details" and date into column called "Event_time" i want to extract all data from table "datamart_queue_details" where  "event_time" > 2020-01-01

Comment: Dumpfile cannot be restored partially. Restore completely then remove unnesessary tables and data.

Comment: To be clear you lost all data for 3 tables for 2020-2021 but 3 tables are fine for to 2019? IF so restore to a staging db and insert from there to corrupted tables for 2020-2021. nb it may be unsafe to take this approach if the 3 tables are in use and inserting/updating for 2020-2021 you should really test to make sure nothing breaks when you do this and you should rethink your backup strategy .